# Can I usue dash_cytoscape with plotly? or other similar network visualisation libraries?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I've looked at https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape and was trying to figure out if I can use this in plotly standard.

I also found this page:

https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/

which seems to indicate no - but wanted to check given I know dash and plotly are very interdependent.

Unfortunately for my usecase I can't use dash as it's running in a cloud jupyter style notebook where I can plot using plotly but can't use tools like jupyter-dash.

Alternatively if someone has a python network visualisation happy to see that as an answer to the question of interactive network visualisation in python.

Comment: You can't use Dash components outside of Dash, but you can still visualize networks using Plotly. It's more complicated and the look is a bit different though. The page about Networks Graphs shows a full example, did you try to play around with it to see if it suits your need ? if you have some data (nodes and edges) to plot, add it to your post with the code you tried, if any.

Comment: Yeah the main thing it doesn't do, unless I'm mistaken is things like dragging a node to put it in a new position, or selecting multiple nodes and doing so

Comment: Yes you're right, these nice features are missing in Plotly. Actually, looking at 
[dash-cytoscape](https://github.com/plotly/dash-cytoscape) repo, it doesn't use regular scatter traces (from plotly.js) for the frontend but [react-cytoscapejs](https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs) component, which relies on [Cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/).